# Where is the default Preference layout?

Tags: android, layout, preference

I would like to make a custom layout for a Preference with just a very small change from the default layout.

Where can I get the default layout for a Preference so I can simply make my minor change without having to create a nearly identical layout from scratch?

Comment: Default preferences for what?  There really IS no default as they would be local to YOUR app.  There are tutorials all over the place to show you how to do this.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking... I know how to make a Preference. What I need is the XML file that Preference uses by default.

Comment: In Eclipse?  (I'm assuming).  There is none.  You need to create a prefences.xml file.

Comment: I just want the xml file that Preference uses by default when there is no custom layout specified. Android is an open source project so it has to be somewhere. I just need this file so that I can make a small edit to it and then put it in my res\layouts folder

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  The preference used by the IDE to generate the default layout file.  Pfft.  No idea.  I just use project template I know compiles and works, and start from there...  It's easier than trying to modify the default setup.

Answer (score 3):

I know, it's an old question but in case anyone is looking for this still (like me):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/preference/preference/res/layout/preference.xml) is the default preference layout for androidx

[This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/preference/preference/res/layout/) folder contains all the widget xml (like SeekBar) as well.